# Rcpp module c++ object finalizer

Tags: rcpp

Why this Rcpp module exposed c++ class doesn't compile when specifying object finalizer? Can you provide a working version?

```
class Exposed{
     public:
        Exposed(){
          printf("constructor has been called\n");
        }

     private:
        int some_field;
}
```

from Rcpp Modules tutorial:
The .finalizer member function of class_ can be used to register a finalizer. A                  finalizer is a free function that takes a pointer to the target class and return void. The finalizer is called before the destructor and so operates on a valid object of the target class. It can be used to perform operations, releasing resources, etc ... The finalizer is called automatically when the R object that encapsulates the C++ object is garbage collected.

```
 static void finalizer_of_exposed( Exposed* ptr ){
      printf("finalizer has been called\n");
 }

 RCPP_MODULE(yada){

    class_<Exposed>("exposed")
        .constructor("")
        .finalizer( &finalizer_of_exposed )    
    ;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it as a `void` function without `static` ?

*Edit 21-Jul-2012:*  You found a bug!  Line 720 of Module.h needs to change:

```
Index: inst/include/Rcpp/Module.h
===================================================================
--- inst/include/Rcpp/Module.h  (revision 3697)
+++ inst/include/Rcpp/Module.h  (working copy)
@@ -717,7 +717,7 @@
     private:

         void SetFinalizer( finalizer_class* f ){
-            if( class_pointer->finalizer_pointer ) delete class_pointer->finalizer ;
+            if( class_pointer->finalizer_pointer ) delete class_pointer->finalizer_pointer ;
             class_pointer->finalizer_pointer = f ; 
         }
```

and I just fixed that in SVN.  Thanks!

Comment: Super quick fix! Updated SVN compiles and provides expected result: new (exposed) -> e; rm (e); gc(); ## finalizer has been called